# Pilight Invalid Option code

Tags: home-automation

I'm having some trouble to re-setup my raspberryPi. I had this running before and am trying to retrace my steps after I reinstalled the whole thing.
I'm struggling with pilight:

```
$ pilight-send -p raw --code="<CODE_WHICH_WORKED_BEFORE>"
$ cat /var/log/pilight.err
[Jun 05 17:41:43:499287] pilight-send: ERROR: invalid option -- '--code'
$ pilight-send -p raw --help
Usage: pilight-send -p raw [options]
 -H  --help         display this message
 -V  --version          display version
 -p  --protocol=protocol    the protocol that you want to control
 -S  --server=x.x.x.x       connect to server address
 -P  --port=xxxx        connect to server port
 -C  --config           config file
 -U  --uuid=xxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxxx UUID

[raw]
 -c --code="raw"        raw code devided by spaces
                (just like the output of debug)

$ pilight-send -p raw -c "<CODE_WHICH_WORKED_BEFORE>"
$ cat /var/log/pilight.err
[Jun 05 17:45:51:779289] pilight-send: ERROR: invalid option -- '-c'
```

Sooo. What am I doing wrong here? I merely copied this from my old bash script so I'm not sure what happened here. Simply installed via apt packages.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself. I had an error in wiring (power of 433MHz transmitter was not connected) so I connected and rebooted the Pi. The command is now working. Not sure if actually caused by wiring error or if reboot (yes, shame on me, I didn't reboot before asking) solved it.